# How can i assign value in first array to new key in second array by comparing id in both arrays . in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, loops

**I want to add the new key to Array2 based on Status and key in Array1 by comparing inspectionId in Array1 and id in Array2.**

```
 Array1 = [ 
      { inspectionId: '4', Status: { CH1: true, CH2: false } },
      { inspectionId: '5', Status: { CH1: false, CH2: true } },
      { inspectionId: '6', Status: { CH1: true, CH2: true } },
      { inspectionId: 'd2', Status: '2020-07-03T11:26:43+05:30' },
      { inspectionId: 'd3', Status: '1' },
      { inspectionId: 'd4', Status: [ '1' ] } 
     ]


 Array2 = [
      { id: '4',
        sectionTitle: 'Inspection Field 4',
        data: 
         [ { key: 'CH1', value: 'Checklist 1', shifts: [] },
           { key: 'CH2', value: 'Checklist 2', shifts: [] } ] 
      },
      { id: '5',
        sectionTitle: 'Inspection Field 5',
        data: 
         [ { key: 'CH1', value: 'Checklist 1', shifts: [] },
           { key: 'CH2', value: 'Checklist 2', shifts: [] } ] 
      },
      { id: '6',
        sectionTitle: 'Inspection Field 6',
        data: 
         [ { key: 'CH1', value: 'Checklist 1', shifts: [] },
           { key: 'CH2', value: 'Checklist 2', shifts: [] } ] 
      } 
           ]
```

Required Formate:

```
data = [
          { id: '4',
            sectionTitle: 'Inspection Field 4',
            data: 
             [ { key: 'CH1', value: 'Checklist 1', shifts: [], status: true },
               { key: 'CH2', value: 'Checklist 2', shifts: [], status: false } ] 
          },
          { id: '5',
            sectionTitle: 'Inspection Field 5',
            data: 
             [ { key: 'CH1', value: 'Checklist 1', shifts: [], status: false },
               { key: 'CH2', value: 'Checklist 2', shifts: [], status: true } ] 
          },
          { id: '6',
            sectionTitle: 'Inspection Field 6',
            data: 
             [ { key: 'CH1', value: 'Checklist 1', shifts: [], status: true },
               { key: 'CH2', value: 'Checklist 2', shifts: [], status: true } ] 
          } 

    ]
```

How can I do so using map or any other method so that I can display the list in section list formate in react-native

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

Have a go with this.

Next time please try something yourself

```js
const Array1 = [ { inspectionId: '4', Status: { CH1: true, CH2: false } }, { inspectionId: '5', Status: { CH1: false, CH2: true } }, { inspectionId: '6', Status: { CH1: true, CH2: true } }, { inspectionId: 'd2', Status: '2020-07-03T11:26:43+05:30' }, { inspectionId: 'd3', Status: '1' }, { inspectionId: 'd4', Status: [ '1' ] } ],
      Array2 = [ { id: '4', sectionTitle: 'Inspection Field 4', data: [ { key: 'CH1', value: 'Checklist 1', shifts: [] }, { key: 'CH2', value: 'Checklist 2', shifts: [] } ] }, { id: '5', sectionTitle: 'Inspection Field 5', data: [ { key: 'CH1', value: 'Checklist 1', shifts: [] }, { key: 'CH2', value: 'Checklist 2', shifts: [] } ] }, { id: '6', sectionTitle: 'Inspection Field 6', data: [ { key: 'CH1', value: 'Checklist 1', shifts: [] }, { key: 'CH2', value: 'Checklist 2', shifts: [] } ] } ];

Array1.forEach(item1 => {
  let section = Array2.find(item2 => item2.sectionTitle === "Inspection Field "+item1.inspectionId);
  if (section) section.data.forEach(data => data.status = item1.Status[data.key]!=null ? item1.Status[data.key] : "N/A" )
})

console.log(Array2)
```